# Vim: how to convert file name to path?

Tags: vim

In [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) script, if I have a file name, how to get it's path? For example, I want to get a path of the temp directory Vim uses. I can get a name of temp file by calling tempname(). But how to extract path from name returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the last path component:

```
fnamemodify(tempname(), ":h")
```